# Get the name of the top derived type through Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I've got the following scenario:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Child().Foo(); //will display "Parent" but I want it to display "Child"
    }
}

class Parent
{
    virtual void Foo()
    {
        var firstFrame = new StackTrace().GetFrames().First();
        var method = firstFrame.GetMethod();
        Console.WriteLine(method.DeclaringType.Fullname);
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{

}
```

As you can see I want the console to display "Child" instead of "Parent". Or to put in another way, I want to walk up the stacktrace and for each method of the stacktrace I would like to get the "this" object.

I could not find any property which serves me the "this" object.

I actually want to list all chain elements of an decorator pattern.

Comment: No duplicate. I want to get the name of the derived object.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see this working is if you override it in the child class, then go one frame up (which in this case, would be the child's foo).

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Child().Foo(); //will display "Child"
    }
}

class Parent
{
    public virtual void Foo()
    {
        StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(1);
        var method = frame.GetMethod();
        Console.WriteLine(method.DeclaringType.FullName);
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public override void Foo()
    {
        base.Foo();
    }
}
```

if you wanted to make this a list, you could put the stack frame section in a loop, and keep going until you run out of foo's. eg:

```
class Parent
{
    public virtual void Foo()
    {
        StackTrace trace = new StackTrace();
        List<StackFrame> frames = new List<StackFrame>(trace.GetFrames());
        var thisMethod = frames[0].GetMethod().Name;
        //we don't want ourselves in the list
        frames.RemoveAt(0);
        foreach (var frame in frames)
        {
            var method = frame.GetMethod();
            //we only want foo's
            if (method.Name == thisMethod)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(method.ReflectedType.FullName);
            }
            else
            {
                // when we've run out, we can get out
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

how about this code:?

```
Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().FullName);
```

instead of this

```
var firstFrame = new StackTrace().GetFrames().First();
var method = firstFrame.GetMethod();
Console.WriteLine(method.DeclaringType.FullName);
```

Comment: Since I am walking up the stacktrace, I can't access the this object. Your solution would work if I would not walk up the stack trace. This is just a minimalistic example.